# Tab autocomplete show results but don't complete

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am using git bash in ConEmu. When there are multiple results for the completion I would like the tab autocomplete to display them in a grid but not to complete with the first result.

I have the results appearing using `bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on` in my `.bashrc` but then the first result is filled and I have to backspace delete it to make my search more specific.

Comment: I'm not sure what bash version your git (github?) comes with, but on my system setting `show-all-if-ambiguous` doesn't complete the first result - it completes what is unambiguous - so if possible completions are `ball`, `nose`, `nowhere`, and `stuff` then typing `n` and hitting TAB will complete to `no` and then list the two words starting with `no` (the ambiguous part). Are you saying that on your system it will complete to `nose` and to select `nowhere` you have to backspace? This is zsh behavior.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Your confirmation that it wasn't show-all-if-ambiguous prompted me to check the other settings more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had `bind 'TAB:menu-complete'` set. This was causing the first result to get filled in.